# Point Of Sale by JCM

Tags: c#, java

I need to create small application for POS. But i can't find enough information for this=(
What i have:
1)Cash-reader - Japan Cash Machine. Model EB-200-RUS. It connecting to comp. by Serial cable RS232.

2)Coins-reader - MFT 08V01. Connecting same.

I can write soft on Java,C#,C++. But Java is preferably))
How to work with this devices?? Can somebody give me links on the API documentation or sample code))
Thanks!!!

P.S. Interesting, what i must to write & read on COM-port for work with it?